# What does 'Yield' mean in this sentence?

Tags: british-english

**Yield** the songs from front to back.
What does yield means? Does this mean order or rearrange?
**Context**: I am given a list of Songs. Consider a playList in iTunes.

Comment: Is there any more context?  I don't know what it means.

Comment: Means nothing to me either (in AmE).

Comment: -1: Not enough context.

Comment: For example, it could mean that you are in a church, with a song on a printed piece of paper, and that you are told after the service that the person coming to collect the songs will begin at the front and work his way to the back.  But probably not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the word *yield* probably means moving the order.

> [yield (v) (#6)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/YIELD) - *Move in order to make room for someone or something.*

The context will help here. Is it done to have some space or simply to change the order of the songs of choice?

Comment: In that definition, "in order to" introduces an adjunct of purpose.  It can be replaced with "to".  Your phrase "moving the order" doesn't have the same meaning.

Comment: And *yield* is intransitive in that sense

Comment: -1: There's not enough context yet to yield an answer.

Comment: Well, if it was "yield to the songs...", then  we could say that it meant; "surrender to them', to "submit"